# IText html to pdf wrapping line

Tags: java, itext

Hello I'm creating javafx app with iText. I have html editor to write text and I want to create pdf from it. Everything works but when I have a really long line that is wrapped in html editor, in pdf it isn't wrapped, its out of page, how can I set wrapping page? here is my code:

```
PdfWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PdfWriter("doc.pdf");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

// Initialize document
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
List<IElement> list = null;
try {
    list = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(editor.getHtmlText());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// add elements to document
for (IElement p : list) {
    document.add((IBlockElement) p);
}

// close document
document.close();
```

I also want to set line spacing for this text

Thank you for help

Comment: A default A4 page is 595 pt wide. If you define a `div` of 700 pt wide, the content will wrap at 700 pt instead of at the "end of the page". I bet your problem is something as trivial as this, but since you don't share your HTML code, you have made your question unanswerable.

Comment: I got html from javafx html editor, I write only in this field

Comment: How is that comment helpful? If your HTML editor allows you to create content that is wider than an A4 page, you should create a document with pages that are wider. There's a 90% chance that you are blaming iText for doing the right thing.

Comment: Here is my html code 
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent 
ultrices enim neque, eu dapibus risus lobortis nec. Integer rhoncus 
imperdiet.&nbsp;</p></body></html>

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tried Joris' code on your HTML snippet, and I added a screen shot of the resulting PDF to his answer. Which version of iText and pdfHTML are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't get any errors for the following code:

```
public class stack_overflow_0008 extends AbstractSupportTicket{

    private static String LONG_PIECE_OF_TEXT = 
        "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary," +
        "Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—" +
        "While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping," +
        "As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door." +
        "Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—" +
        "Only this and nothing more.";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        

        PdfWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PdfWriter(getOutputFile());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
        List<IElement> list = null;
        try {
            list = HtmlConverter.convertToElements("<p>" + LONG_PIECE_OF_TEXT + "</p>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (IElement p : list) {
            document.add((IBlockElement) p);
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

The document is a single (A4) page PDF with one string neatly wrapped.

I think perhaps the content of your string is to blame?
Could you post the HTML you get from this editor object?

**Update:**

Using the code from this answer on the HTML shared in a new comment to the question, I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the content is distributed over two lines. No content "falls off the page."